# What are ALL the 119 badges that one can achieve (via Steam)

Tags: torchlight-2

Torchlight 2

There is a list of locked badges shown on steam, but its only a subset of the full list.

What is the list of ALL the locked badges/achievements that one can achieve.
It shows there are 119.

Are there MORE achievements than 119 that is shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to find all of the achievements here:

http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Achievements_%28T2%29

It seems like there are 4 unachieveable achievements, you can find them at the bottom of that page.

According to this:

http://steamcommunity.com//app/200710/discussions/0/846959362265821814/

They have been removed from the game.